# I want to hide the customization yith pos tab for all users aside from admin. how can i do that?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to hide the customization yith pos tab for all users aside from admin. how can i do that?

screenshot :

[image]

i tried this but did not work

```
add_filter( 'yith_pos_panel_settings_tabs_array',  'filter_yith_pos_panel_settings_tabs_array', 200, 1 );
function filter_yith_pos_panel_settings_tabs_array( $tabs_array ) {
    // Only for "shipping_manager" user role
    if( current_user_can( 'YITH_POS_Manager' ) ) {
        // Remove some specific tabs
        unset( $tabs_array['customization'], 
    }
    
    return $tabs_array;
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried executing the following line in your hook? `echo '<pre>', print_r( $tabs_array, 1 ), '</pre>';` That way you know if your hook is running effectively and what `$tabs_array` contains specifically

Comment: have tried that too but it didnt work. 

i got a workaround though. to edit the plugin files to show it only if admin not manager.

Comment: **1)** Couldn't it be that the filter hook you're using just doesn't exist? where did you find it? **2)** Never, ever modify plugin files directly